# angular: How to change the data type using $formatters and $parsers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, type-conversion

Using ngModel.$formatters and ngModel.$parsers i'm trying to create a directive to change the data-type from model to view and vice versa.

The problem is when i use `<input type="number">`
In that case `toView` receives 'undefined' as value, but not string data. ("1234")

If i remove type=number works fine, but the input element is not what i want.

There are any way to get it working?

if not, there are another way to achieve this aim? (the model MUST be string, the input MUST be type="number")

[PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/n1Z2BdjDC6pnQjEc82AQ?p=info)

**javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('module', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.model.number = "1234";
});

app.directive('numberConverter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: {
      pre: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

        function toModel(value) {
          return "" + value; // convert to string
        }

        function toView(value) {
          return parseInt(value); // convert to number
        }

        ngModel.$formatters.unshift(toView);
        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(toModel);
      },
      post: function() {}
    }
  };
});
```

**html**

```
<input type="number" number-converter ng-model="model.number">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, my original answer wasn't quite right.

Here is an updated directive that will correctly store the value as a string but edit it as a number.

It's important that the priority of the directive be greater than 0 (the default priority) so that it runs after the ngModel directive does. This makes sure that you're adding your formatters and parsers after the defaults (otherwise you're just pushing to an empty list and the default processors will be added after yours anyway).

```
app.directive('numberConverter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority: 1,
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            function toModel(value) {
                return "" + value; // convert to string
            }

            function toView(value) {
                return parseInt(value); // convert to number
            }

            ngModel.$formatters.push(toView);
            ngModel.$parsers.push(toModel);
        }
    };
});
```

Updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/l8c1GGBeIX4dawLZJfoC?p=preview

Comment: `{link: function(){}}` is a short-hand for `{link: {postLink: function(){}}}` - they're the same.

Comment: +1, and I took the liberty to fork the plnkr and add model field for `type` to easier demonstrate that it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/uCLmwZhjwlPtmXnj5Hw3?p=preview